# Node js - fs.readFile & fs.writeStream

Tags: node.js, zip, fs

I am writing a gallery system which currently shows a list of photos on a page and then gives the user the option to download a zip of the entire gallery. If this zip doesn't already exist, it is generated on-the-fly, but it can take a while to generate in it's current state (sometimes around a minute). This is the code I've got so far:

```
if (fs.existsSync(zipPath)) {
        callback(downloadPath);
    } else {

        socket.emit('preparingZip');

        fs.readdir(galleryPath, function(err, listOfPhotos) {

            async.each(listOfPhotos, function(photo, cb) {

                if (photo != 'thumbnails') {

                    var photoPath = galleryPath+'/'+photo;

                    fs.readFile(photoPath, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) { console.log(err); }
                        console.log(photoPath);
                        zip.file(photo, data);
                        cb();
                    });

                } else {
                    cb();
                }

            }, function(err) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }

                var data = zip.generate({base64:false,compression:'DEFLATE'});

                fs.writeFile(zipPath, data, 'binary', function(err) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); }
                    callback(downloadPath);
                });

            });

        });
    }
```

I have read that fs.writeFile shouldn't be used in this example, and that I should use fs.writeStream instead to make it a lot more efficient, but I can't find any examples of how to use fs.readFile & fs.writeStream together. Could someone please explain how I would do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Found a module called zip-stream in the end which works great (although the documentation isn't brilliant).